# Calling a PHP from another PHP in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a main index.php. There is a href link on this PHP, from which I am calling another PHP. There are some jdoc statements in the second PHP. These don't get executed. If I use 'include' in the index.php, then it works properly. It also works if I use href pointing to a location in the same index.php.

index.php code:

```
<a href="/joomla16/templates/zmtemplate/second.php">Trial</a>
```

second.php

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="Header3"             style="none" /> 

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="Header14"            style="none" />
```

Comment: as far as i know, in joomla there is a .htaccess file which rewrites every url to `index.php` so your second php script is never executed. you may have to edit `.htaccess` file to not redirect your `second.php`

Comment: second.php would have to be running joomla as well. you can't just point a url directly at it and expect joomla to pick up on it.

Comment: Bansi, Thanks...I am new to Joomla...can you tell me how to edit .htaccess to not to redirect second.php

Comment: Marc, can u elaborate what does second.php would hv to be running joomla mean? how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are trying to access a page that is not part of Joomla framework.

In Joomla you can't just explicitly use new pages like `second.php` or something else.

Its based on MVC, you have to write `component` or `module` for your task based on your requirement.

Component gives a wide option for your requirement like form submission ,different pages (layouts) etc. Module is the smallest unit it just display the content (from DB or static) any where in the view page (you can include multiple module in a page.)

Another `Dirty` option is to achieve your requirement very quickly is as below.

Instead of loading `second.php` inside template use it in the root then include Joomla frame works to that page, USE *ht-access* to create some `SEF URL` for this page, you can use below script to include Joomla frame work.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root,means path to Joomla installation
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

hope it make sense..

Or you have to describe more in details what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello..tx for the reply. I am new to Joomla...can you tell me how the component can be used for form submission? can you point me good sites which explain how MVC pattern work for Joomla?

Comment: The best tutorial for MVC is Joomla doc http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component you can check how they implement also you will get a sample component to download, download that go through the structure and modify based on your requirement its easy.

Comment: Hello...from what I gather after reading is that if I'll have to make a component for the second.php and in the index.php, I call this component instead of the href link...correct?

Comment: Yes, you can create a component and its view (layout) can be link from menu system or from index.php

Comment: I hv created a component from a sample one. I tested it by passing the name of the component in option of index.php. It is supposed to echo 'Hello World'. The URL executes correctly but the message is not getting displayed

Comment: how you access the component like www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_hello&view=default or something like it will works.

Comment: yes I access in the same way but nothing gets displayed

Comment: just make sure the control comes inside view.html.php and default.php like echo 'somthing'; on view file too, Also try to pass controller name too.

Comment: when I deploy the same on to the localhost I get 'internal server error' and when I deploy the same on main server, I get the following error :Fatal error: Call to undefined method JController::getInstance() in /public_html/joomla30/components/com_comp1/comp1.php on line 10

Comment: This is sorted...used JLegacy classes...thanks for all the solutions

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in the second.php file you have imported the Joomla! framework functions in order for you to use functions such as `<jdoc:include type="modules" style="xhtml" />` and the rest. Try something like this in the very beginning of your second.php file;

```
<?php
 defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
?>
```

After doing that, now you can call your jdoc include statement and see if it works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla needs an entry point file which sets up the Joomla application and fires off all the steps involved in generating your page. This is not the `index.php` file in your template directory. It is the `index.php` file in your base Joomla directory.

In your template directory, the `index.php` file is just the default template (not the entry point to the application). You can load a different template by passing `tmpl=<filename>` in the query string of your url (there are also some other good ways of accomplishing this). But the templating system is pretty versatile, you may not actually need a different template file at all.

Comment: Hello...Tx for the reply. Cn u point me a good URL on how joomla works?

Comment: Well, that's a pretty big topic. The wiki is pretty good: http://docs.joomla.org/ and if you are developing an extension of some kind, you might look here: http://docs.joomla.org/Category:Development but if you have some more specifics about what you are trying to do I might be able to give some more useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn HTML, CSS, Then PHP & MYSQL. Once you understand all that you can learn Joomla.

PHP & MYSQL are somewhat optional but I strongly recommend understanding them to fully use Joomla.

Your `<jdoc>` statements need to be used within a Joomla template within a Joomla installation. You can't just put a `<jdoc>` statement in any random index.php file and hope they work. You need the joomla template engine to render those tags correctly.

Your right if you use include() in any plain .php file like this :

```
<?php include('filename.php'); ?>
```

That will work without Joomla. So you need to start with the basics first.

Check out Lynda.com for training videos on all theses subjects or even lookup theses subjects on youtube.com